# Swift iOS -Push uiview down while typing inside textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a textfield that I set to a height of >= 50. Underneath the textfield I have uiview that is anchored to the bottom of the textfield. Once the textfield gets past the 50 point height I want it to push the uiview down so the text continues downward. What's happening right now is it hits the bottom of itself and instead of pushing the uiview down it scrolls the text up and the uiview doesn't move.

How can i get the textfield to stop scrolling up and instead push the uiview down once the textfield goes past the 50 point height? I can use a textfield with number of lines to 0 instead but I'd rather use a textfield.

```
// imageView is pinned to the top of the screen

textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iamgeView.bottomAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
textView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 50).isActive = true

bottomLine.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
bottomLine.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
bottomLine.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
bottomLine.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.5).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable scrolling on the textField

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```